# Filtering null values in JPQL

Tags: spring, jpa

Good Morning

I have a problem when I try to receive all params in JPQL as null . If @Query receive all params as null I think that result will be a list of all content.

The wrapper object.

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ProductWrapper {

    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private int quantity;
    private long price;

}
```

The Controller layer.

```
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/products")
    public class ProductController {
    
        @Autowired
        private ProductService service;
    
         @GetMapping("/test")
            private ResponseEntity<Page<Product>> findAllProductsWithPageable(
        ProductWrapper productWrapper,                                                                 
@PageableDefault(page = 0, size = 10) Pageable pageable) {
                Page<Product> allProducts = service.findAllProductsWithPageable(pageable,productWrapper);
                return ResponseEntity.ok(allProducts);
            }
```

In Service layer I call at repository like this.

```
public Page<Product> findAllProductsWithPageable(Pageable pageable,ProductWrapper productWrapper) {
        return repository.findAllQuery(
                productWrapper.getName(),
                productWrapper.getSurname(),
                productWrapper.getQuantity(),
                productWrapper.getPrice(),
                PageRequest.of(pageable.getPageNumber(), pageable.getPageSize(), Sort.by(sorts)));
    }
```

The complex part of this development is the repository.

```
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product,Integer> {
    /**JPQL**/
    @Query("SELECT c FROM Product c WHERE"
            + " (:name is null or c.name = :name)"
            + " or (:surname is null or c.surname = :surname)"
            + "or (:quantity is null or c.quantity = :quantity)"
            + "or (:price is null or c.price = :price)")
    Page<Product> findAllQuery(@Param("name") String name,
                               @Param("surname") String surname,
                               @Param("quantity") int quantity,
                               @Param("price") long price,
                               Pageable pageable);
}
```

Could anyone helps to me to ? I would like to add like in name and surname JPA.

Regards.

Comment: I don't understand you question. Can you please provide an example how your data looks like and what you expect as result?

Comment: Clarify your question please. Your title says about filtering null values and in the end of your post you ask how to add like in name and surname. What is your exact question please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the SQL should be

```
 @Query("SELECT c FROM Product c WHERE 1=1 "
            + " or (:name is null or c.name = :name)"
            + " or (:surname is null or c.surname = :surname)"
            + " or (:quantity is null or c.quantity = :quantity)"
            + " or (:price is null or c.price = :price)")
```

You need **1=1** to avoid syntax error when all params are null.